How many lashes do false witnesses receive?
If two witnesses claim that a person is liable to receive lashes, and their testimony is found to be false, do they receive the amount of lashes that that person would have received, i.e. only the amount that he would be able to handle, or do they receive as many lashes as they themselves can handle?

Rambam (Edut, 18) says they receive only as many lashes as they can handle:

וְאִם הֵעִידוּ בְּמַלְקוֹת לוֹקֶה כָּל אֶחָד מֵהֶן כִּשְׁאָר
מְחֻיְּבֵי מַלְקוֹת. וְאוֹמְדִין כֹּחוֹ וּמַלְקִין אוֹתוֹ.‏
If they testified falsely with regard to a transgression punishable by
lashes, each one of them is lashed as are all those obligated to be
lashed. We estimate their capacity to bear the lashes and they are
lashed.


Right. The penalty is "lashes." So we apply that penalty to the false witnesses. The rule of reduce-from-39-to-what-they-can-bear is not part of the penalty, but rather a practical point of how to carry it out. Therefore it's tailored to whomever's being whipped right now.
